# How to loop through each item in chrome.storage, when key values are unknown?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is it possible for me to loop through every item stored using `chrome.storage.sync.set`?
All the values stored have a URL and some CSS code, but the problem is, I don't know the URLs. I was thinking of something like this in my popup.js:

```js
for (item in chrome.storage.sync.get()) {
    alert("Executed for ${url}")
    // How would I get url?
}
```

However, that never gets executed, even without the invalid variable.

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `chrome` API that return a Promise or can accept a callback are **asynchronous**.

#### ManifestV3: use `await` inside a function declared as `async`

```js
async function enumStorage() {
  const all = await chrome.storage.sync.get();
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(all)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

#### ManifestV2: use a callback

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(all => {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(all)) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools and console: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I am calling the function using just `enumStorage()`, and it gets executed, but it doesn't appear the `for` loop gets executed.

Comment: The code is correct, so you need to debug what happens in your real extension.

Comment: It was indeed my problem; I was using `chrome.storage.local` instead of `chrome.storage.sync` like you used in your answer.